# How to stop pathfinder in illustrator cc from automatically editing / rounding shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder, distort

So I've been using Illustrator for 6 years, and thought I knew everything about the pathfinder feature. Today I tried to use the merge pathfinder tool on some outlined text, and have gotten a 'neatly' merged object, and not the final object I wanted. Take a look at the pictures, and tell me how to stop it from happening.

- I already checked off Align to Pixel Grid and Scale Strokes and Effects.

P.S. I want all the text to merge like the 'y' did.

[image]
[image]

Best,
Tea

Comment: Pixel snapping possibly?

Comment: There's no reason I'm aware of for that to occur. If the original shape is merged the O should be going more into the B and D. Something else is going on that's unable to be determined from the info you've provided. Have you tried Unite instead? It's probably the better command in this usage anyways - though the results should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

not entirely sure why this is happening but i find it can help to just select two objects at a time and merge. ie select first two, merge, select the just merged and the next object, merge, rinse and repeat until done.